# Excel Indirect with Count

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook with different sheets for each month. I made another sheet where I put the months in A1 down.
I wanted to use Counta (for A:A in the months' sheets) and indirect together but I am getting the result "1" with my formula.

Please help:

=COUNTA(INDIRECT(SheetNames!A1&"!A:A"))

I would also eventually like to do the same for countif. If you can please explain what I missed that will help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying out your formula it works perfectly unless you've got a space in the worksheet name.
Try this formula:
`=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'" & SheetNames!A1 & "'!A:A"))`

When a sheet name contains a space then the sheet name must be enclosed within apostrophes.  So `=COUNTA('Sheet 4'!A:A)` is a valid formula, while `=COUNTA(Sheet 4!A:A)` will not work and causes all kinds of problems.
The INDIRECT formula needs a valid reference as a string (rather than an actual reference) to calculate - so **"'" & SheetNames!A1 & "'!A:A"** returns the string **'Sheet 4'!A:A**.

Comment: Thank you very much! it seems the reason it didn't work was because I didn't put spaces as you have. can you please explain the significance of {" ' "}?

Comment: Clear and concise! Thanks again and Happy new year!